# Generic path but the same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Trying to create a file renderer but I do not know how to create in a right way. The snippet that I have is that one but is super repetitive:

```html
<Routes>
  <Route path='/explorer' element={<Files>}>
    <Route path=':root' element={<Files>}>
      <Route path=':branch' element={<Files>}>
        <Route path=':leaf' element={<Files>} />
        ...
       </Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Examples:

- /explorer/home
- /explorer/home/username
- /explorer/home/username/documents
- ...

If I use `useParams` hook from `react-router-dom` sometimes some params would be *undefined* and I would like to ignore these params (looping all params I could do it but I do not think is the best practise)
With that params after I create an array and make a request to display all the files or the folders of the selected path (*/explorer/home/username*)

Is it some way to set a generic number of params for just one component and get a `params` object with just the need it params?

```html
<Routes>
  <Route path='/explorer' element={<Files>}>
    <Route path='??' element={<Files>}>
  </Route>
<Routes>
```

Comment: Have you tried passing a single parameter to your route, containing the full path to your file / folder ?
This way you just have to split your path on your Files component to get the full route !

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for. What does "some way to set a generic number of `params` for just one component and get a params object with just the need it params" mean exactly? Your first snippet seems fine to me. What exactly is the issue you are trying to solve for? Is the issue one of "file structure depth", i.e. you don't know ahead of time how many route params are needed? Can you provide a [mcve] for what you are trying to do?

Comment: @A.Vinuela and how shall I format full path? because if I add a slash symbol, react-router will interpret as a new param?

Comment: You can escape the slashes in your url as "%2F"

Comment: @A.Vinuela could you give me an example?

Comment: @DrewReese the issue of my problem comes as you said when I do not know the deep of the file path. If I have a path like */explorer/home/username/documents* all the params would be defined using `useParams` hook. But what about if the path is deeper as */explorer/home/username/documents/math/exercises*?
Thats why in the last snippet path attribute (path='??'), I set that one, if there is some way to set some regular expression and after get all the params with `useParams` hook

Comment: RRDv6 route paths don't support or use regular expressions, that feature was removed. See [What Happened to Regexp Routes Paths](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/faq#what-happened-to-regexp-routes-paths) for details. I suggest passing a path value as a query param instead of a path param. This way the route matching is separate from the path value and you can parse the path however you need to for display.

Comment: @DrewReese that could be another option but it is not that elegant as the path param option. So in that case, the only way is to do with params as I did in the first snipped with nested routes right? add some routes and extract data from there. Thanks for your time :))

Comment: Correct, if you want to use route path params then you need to define a route for any combination of params you want to handle. IMHO it could be argued using a single route and processing a queryString is more elegant, it's ***much*** less code and easier to read and maintain, but to each their own. :D You could try a single route with path `"/explorer/*` and try to read/process `location.pathname` to extract "the rest of the path".

Comment: Uuh thats nice option with `*` character. Now having both options, will you still implement the query string? In that case, how shall I implement the path, `explorer?root=home&b1=username&b2=documents&leaf=math`
After to set that params in the query, shall I use `setSearchParams`? Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't think so... I was trying to think of an alternative RRDv6 way to specify everything in the URL path not using route params or queryString, and then applying some string parsing on the `location.pathname` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion I have for a simple way to manage this would be to render a single route with no path parameters and a trailing wildcard character `"*"` to continue matching after the first path segment.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/explorer/*" element={<Files />} />
</Routes>
```

The `Files` component will then access the entire `location.pathname` and apply a little string manipulation to get the file/directory structure from the URL path segments.

Example:

```
const Files = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const path = pathname
    .slice(1)   // remove leading "/"
    .split("/") // split path directories
    .slice(1);  // remove leading "explorer" route path

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

| pathname | path array |
| --- | --- |
| `/explorer/home` | `["home"]` |
| `/explorer/home/username` | `["home", "username"]` |
| `/explorer/home/username/documents` | `["home", "username", "documents"]` |
| `/explorer/home/username/documents/math/exercises` | `["home", "username", "documents", "math", "exercises"]` |

What you do with `path` from here is up to you.

[image]

[image: Edit generic-path-but-the-same-component]

The other solution I'd proposed was to pass the path as a query parameter, i.e. `"/explorer?path=/home`, and apply a similar path string processing. Perhaps something like the following:

```
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
const stringPath = searchParams.get('path');

const path = stringPath
  .slice(1)    // remove leading "/"
  .split("/"); // split path directories
```

Comment: The first option really like, and its quite easy! thanks for your time